# 'Connection refused' in Laravel when I try 'php artisan migrate'

Tags: php, laravel, macos, migrate

When I try `php artisan migrate` in MacOS terminal, it shows the following -

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = project and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

      +36 vendor frames 
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I have tried

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:install
```

but it's still showing the same message.

Comment: Can you share the ```env``` file have you created database

Comment: Are you sure your `mysql` service running in the port which you specified in `.env`?

Answer (score 0):

Check `.env` file. In my case, I had to change `DB_PORT` from `3307` to `3306` (check what's your port)